# Shut EXCEL .EXE *32 process

Tags: c#

Everytime i run this i get new process EXCEL .EXE *32. How to shut it down after getting info from Excel?

```
        FileStream fileStream;
        string temp = "D:\\Temp";
        string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName());
        string path = Path.Combine(temp, file + ".xslx");
        using (fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            memoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
        }

        Excel.Application excelApplication;
        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook;
        Excel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet;
        Excel.Range excelRange;
        Excel.Range excelCheckRange;
        DataTable dataTable = null;

        try
        {
            excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
            excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(path, ReadOnly: true);
            excelWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            //TO DO
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end of your work, you should use

```
if (excelWorkbook != null)    
  excelWorkbook.Close();
if(excelApplication != null)
  excelApplication.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
> ```

That will indeed start up Excel.

To close that process you need to ensure you have no references to the Excel application object, or any other part of it (eg. a `Range`). Then the GC will eventually clear it out. You can speed things up using [`Application.Quit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.quit.aspx) (but note what the documentation says about unsaved workbooks).

Comment: Just note that OP opens workbook in read-only mode, so there shouldn't be problems with unsaved workbooks :)